# create a database in pyspark using Python API's only

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm unable to locate any API to create a database in pyspark. All I can find is SQL based approach.

catalog doesn't mention a python method to create a database.

Is this even possible? I am trying to avoid using SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it might be a suboptimal solution, but you can call a `CREATE DATABASE` statement using SparkSession's `sql` method to create a database, like this:

```py
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF EXISTS test_db")
```

It's not *pure* PySpark API, but this way you don't have to switch context to SQL completely, to create a database :)

Comment: I don't see a pyspark api for this at the moment, so this is what I am doing.  There is an endless list of issues with mixing STRING SQL in a production application unless forced.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is nothing else you can about it at the moment.